# How to show the selected user is admin in php

Tags: php

In one query i am getting all the user details in the user table.

```
$userDetails =  $dbUser ->getAllUsers();
```

In second query i am getting the user details which are there in the selected group.

```
$groupMemberDetails = $dbGroupMembers ->getAllGroupMembers($groupId);
```

But if the user is in selected group i have to show them as selected remaining user as unselected and also if he is owner show it as admin append to his name.

I have done following code but i am not getting properly.

Please correct me.

```
foreach ( $userDetails as $user ) {

    $userId = $user['user_id'];
    $userFirstName = $user['first_name'];
    $userName = '';

    $selected = "";
    foreach ( $groupMemberDetails as $groupMemberDetail ) {
        $groupMemberId = $groupMemberDetail['user_id'];
        if($groupMemberId == $userId) {
            $selected = "selected";
        }
        $isAdmin = $groupMemberDetail['is_owner'];
        if($isAdmin) {
            $userName = $userFirstName . "(admin)";
        } else {
            $userName = $userFirstName;
        }

    }
    echo '<option value="'.$userId.'" '.$selected.'>'. $userName . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before foreach i have declared

```
 $adminStr = "";
```

Then in if condition i have written like this

```
if($groupMemberId == $userId) { 
    $selected = "selected";

    $isAdmin = $groupMemberDetail['is_owner'];
    $adminStr = $isAdmin ? "(Admin)" : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset Selected on each loop

```
  foreach ( $groupMemberDetails as $groupMemberDetail ) {
    $groupMemberId = $groupMemberDetail['user_id'];
    //You need this line
    $selected = '';

    if($groupMemberId == $userId) {
        $selected = "selected";
    }
```